Trying to deploy a Custom Model into OpenSearch throws a RuntimeError: KeyError: token_type_ids
For a specific use case, I had to deploy a custom model into OpenSearch, First of the all, I exported a HuggingFace Model into TorchScript and had registered successfully then I tried to deploy it but unfortunately deploy operation failed and returns the following error :
    {
  "model_id": "Guem7I4BM4PGcXAkFYKV",
  "task_type": "DEPLOY_MODEL",
  "function_name": "TEXT_EMBEDDING",
  "state": "FAILED",
  "worker_node": [
    "d7zdcxaASDyFKGX7AhlG0g",
    "5fc7S9yJQQCWarLbAnVESg",
    "TPu-1KznRzCwj8tQAgHOMQ"
  ],
  "create_time": 1713367889874,
  "last_update_time": 1713368035088,
  "error": """
                          {"d7zdcxaASDyFKGX7AhlG0g":"The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, serialized code (most recent call last):
                          \n  File \"code/__torch__.py\", line 12, in forward
                          \n    input_ids = inputs[\"input_ids\"]
                          \n    attention_mask = inputs[\"attention_mask\"]
                          \n    input = inputs[\"token_type_ids\"]
                          \n            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
                          \n    _0 = (model).forward(input_ids, attention_mask, input, )
                          \n    return {\"sentence_embedding\": _0}
                          \n
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, original code (most recent call last):
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(1074): trace_module
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(806): trace
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(43): export_to_torchscript
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(52): <module>
                          \nRuntimeError: KeyError: token_type_ids
                          \n","5fc7S9yJQQCWarLbAnVESg":"The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, serialized code (most recent call last):
                          \n  File \"code/__torch__.py\", line 12, in forward
                          \n    input_ids = inputs[\"input_ids\"]
                          \n    attention_mask = inputs[\"attention_mask\"]
                          \n    input = inputs[\"token_type_ids\"]
                          \n            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
                          \n    _0 = (model).forward(input_ids, attention_mask, input, )
                          \n    return {\"sentence_embedding\": _0}
                          \n
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, original code (most recent call last):
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(1074): trace_module
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(806): trace
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(43): export_to_torchscript
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(52): <module>
                          \nRuntimeError: KeyError: token_type_ids
                          \n","TPu-1KznRzCwj8tQAgHOMQ":"The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, serialized code (most recent call last):
                          \n  File \"code/__torch__.py\", line 12, in forward
                          \n    input_ids = inputs[\"input_ids\"]
                          \n    attention_mask = inputs[\"attention_mask\"]
                          \n    input = inputs[\"token_type_ids\"]
                          \n            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
                          \n    _0 = (model).forward(input_ids, attention_mask, input, )
                          \n    return {\"sentence_embedding\": _0}
                          \n
                          \nTraceback of TorchScript, original code (most recent call last):
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(1074): trace_module
                          \n/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py(806): trace
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(43): export_to_torchscript
                          \n/Users/opensearch/CustomModel/TEST/import_torch.py(52): <module>
                          \nRuntimeError: KeyError: token_type_ids\n"}
    """,
  "is_async": true
}

Here is python script I used to export the model into TorchScript
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, PreTrainedTokenizer
from transformers.utils import PaddingStrategy
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer


class TorchScriptWrapper(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(TorchScriptWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.model = model

    def forward(self, inputs: dict):
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = self.model(inputs)
        return {"sentence_embedding": outputs['sentence_embedding']}


def export_to_torchscript(model_name: str, is_sentence_transformer: bool, output_path: str, max_seq_length: int = 128):
    tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    if is_sentence_transformer:
        model = SentenceTransformer(model_name, device="cpu")
    else:
        model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model.eval()

    # Define example text
    text = "This is a test string"

    # Create inputs
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding=PaddingStrategy.MAX_LENGTH, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_seq_length)

    # Instantiate the wrapper class
    model_wrapper = TorchScriptWrapper(model)

    # Unpack HF batch encoding into a regular dict
    new_inputs = {}
    new_inputs["input_ids"] = inputs["input_ids"]
    new_inputs["attention_mask"] = inputs["attention_mask"]
    if inputs.get("token_type_ids", None) is not None:
        new_inputs["token_type_ids"] = inputs["token_type_ids"]

    # Trace the wrapper class
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model_wrapper, new_inputs, strict=False)

    # Save traced model to file
    traced_model.save(output_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load pre-trained model and tokenizer
    model_name = "sentence-transformers/LaBSE"
    export_to_torchscript(model_name, True, output_path="torchscript_labse.pt")

PS : The error occured even though the token_type_ids key is part of the inputs dictionary

The issue has been sorted out !
here is the updated script that fixed the issue
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer, PreTrainedTokenizer
from transformers.utils import PaddingStrategy
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer


class TorchScriptWrapper(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(TorchScriptWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.model = model

    def forward(self, inputs: dict):
        inputs['token_type_ids'] = torch.zeros_like(inputs['attention_mask'], dtype=torch.int)
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = self.model(inputs)
        return {"sentence_embedding": outputs['sentence_embedding']}


def export_to_torchscript(model_name: str, is_sentence_transformer: bool, output_path: str, max_seq_length: int = 128):
    tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    if is_sentence_transformer:
        model = SentenceTransformer(model_name, device="cpu")
    else:
        model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model.eval()

    # Define example text
    text = "This is a test string"

    # Create inputs
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding=PaddingStrategy.MAX_LENGTH, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_seq_length)

    # Instantiate the wrapper class
    model_wrapper = TorchScriptWrapper(model)

    # Unpack HF batch encoding into a regular dict
    new_inputs = {}
    new_inputs["input_ids"] = inputs["input_ids"]
    new_inputs["attention_mask"] = inputs["attention_mask"]
    #if inputs.get("token_type_ids", None) is not None:
    #    new_inputs["token_type_ids"] = inputs["token_type_ids"]

    # Trace the wrapper class
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model_wrapper, new_inputs, strict=False)

    # Save traced model to file
    traced_model.save(output_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load pre-trained model and tokenizer
    model_name = "sentence-transformers/LaBSE"
    export_to_torchscript(model_name, True, output_path="torchscript_labse.pt")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
